# Color gt Table in R with Specified Ranges

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-visualization, gt

I'd like to fill the cells of a gt table based on a specified range of values. Any value greater than 0.95 = green, 0.85-0.95 = yellow, and below 0.85 should be red. I have tried RColorBrewer's RdYlGn palette but had trouble supplying a range of values to that.

Here is some sample data:

```
City         Jan   Feb   Mar  
Kansas City  .94  .90   .98
Chicago      .82  .87   .78
Detroit      .80  .92   .81
Miami        .98  1.00  .94
```

Answer (score 1):

gt's `data_color` works well with color palettes defined by the `scales` package, so you can define your own binned color palette with `col_bin` and pass that to `data_color`. More details/examples on color mapping in scales can be found here: https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/col_numeric.html.

```
library(gt)
library(scales)

data <- data.frame(City = c('Kansas City','Chicago','Detroit','Miami'), 
                   Jan = c(.94, .82, .80, .98), 
                   Feb = c(.90, .87, .92, 1.0), 
                   Mar = c(.98, .78, .81, .94))

palette <- col_bin(palette=c('red','yellow','green'), bins=c(0,.85,.95,1.0))

gt(data) %>%
  data_color(columns=c('Jan','Feb','Mar'), colors=palette, apply_to='text')
```

Producing these results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

I used `orange` instead of `yellow` -> better to read but you can change easily.
Somehow 0.92 is not registered in the sequence so I put it by hand!

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
tbl1 <- df %>%
  gt()
nm1 <- names(df[,2:4])
 

for(i in seq_along(nm1)) {
  
  tbl1 <- tbl1 %>%
    tab_style(
      style = list(
        cell_text(color = "green", weight = "bold")
        #cell_fill(color = "red")
      ),
      locations = cells_body(
        columns = nm1[i],
        
        rows = tbl1$`_data`[[nm1[i]]] > 0.95 
      )
    ) %>%
    
    tab_style(
      style = list(
        cell_text(color = "red", weight = "bold")
        # cell_fill(color = "blue")
      ),
      locations = cells_body(
        columns = nm1[i],
        
        rows = tbl1$`_data`[[nm1[i]]] < 0.85 
      )
    ) %>% 
    
    tab_style(
      style = list(
        cell_text(color = "orange", weight = "bold")
        # cell_fill(color = "blue")
      ),
      locations = cells_body(
        columns = nm1[i],
        
        rows = tbl1$`_data`[[nm1[i]]] %in% c(0.92, seq(0.85,0.95, 0.01))
      )
    ) 
  
}
tbl1
```

[image]